# T-SQL max sales date and price on that sales

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a sales table and products table. I'd like to retrieve the last sales and the product price of the last sales. Is there a query that can do this in a simple way:

```
Select Max(s.SalesDate), p.ProductName, Max(s.Price)
From Sales s 
inner join products p
group by p.ProductName
```

This doesn't work because `max(price)` is not from the last sale

Comment: Would you like to add an `ON` clause to that `JOIN`?

Comment: Should work if you finish the `join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from 
(
Select s.SalesDat, p.ProductName, Maxs.Price
     , row_number() over (partition by p.ProductName order  by s.SalesDat desc) as rn
From Sales s 
inner join products p
) tt 
where tt.rn = 1
```

clearly you are missing a join condition